# How to use Stream instead of byte[] in C# client with a Java MTOM webservice

Tags: c#, java, web-services, cxf, mtom

I have a java webservice generated with CXF, and with MTOM enabled.

On the java side, I'm using DataHandler instead of byte[] to send a large file.

If I generate a Java client, it is working fine, declaring DataHandler on the client as well.

The problem is when I try to create a C#.net client.

Using Visual Studio 2010 to generate the client code, it declares the field as byte[] and not as a Stream. This is a problem, because on the client side it is reading and allocation all data to fill the byte[].

Seeing some examples of MTOM and C#, they use Strem instead of byte[].

How can I generate the client code to use Stream instead of byte[] in C#?

Here is the wsdl section using the mtom:

```
<xs:complexType name="wsDtoCampoRespostaFotografia">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:wsDtoCampoResposta">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" minOccurs="0"   name="valorRespostaFotografia" ns4:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Edit:
The problem I'm having is memory allocation. When reading a lot of records with, or a record with a large file, the client throws an exception (due to memory allocation).

Calling the webservice using byte[], the client loads all data in memory, even before giving the result to the rest of the code to handle it. When using Stream I can have access to the result of the webservice, and I can write the content of the Stream to a file, without loading into memory, avoiding out of memory problems.

Comment: It's all bytes in the end anyway, not sure why there would be a problem with this. Have you tried?

Comment: @KyleC I'm guessing the OP deliberately wants to avoid the buffering, and have the service be able to stream binary data on both ends. (I understand that's what MTOM is meant to accomplish, by sending the binary bits outside of the main SOAP message. I imagine the read end would have to have some restrictions, as only allowing you to read the binary attachments once in sequence. It's also entirely possible this just isn't supported by WCF.)

Comment: @Kyle I edited the question adding the reason I need Stream.

Comment: @millimoose So in WCF I can have just one attachment per webservice result? Do you thing this is my problem? I'm reading multiple records (wsDtoCampoRespostaFotografia) in the same call, so I have multiple attachments in the same result. I can't do that in .net?

Comment: @RafaelCeravolo I'm... not at all sure really, I'm going by documentation skimming so far. I'll poke at this in VS later since I only have access to ideone right now.

Comment: @RafaelCeravolo Having poked at this further, I don't think you're in much luck. Seems WCF streaming is implemented in a proprietary fashion, although it does use MTOM. However, I couldn't force WCF to generate a streaming client for a plain MTOM service, it seems to expect streaming services to follow a specific pattern. The documentation also implies handling multiple attachment in a single response is right out. *Maybe* if you restructures your Java service to download the attachments in separate requests. The overhead should be negligible if the files are large enough to require streaming.

Comment: And that's a fairly strong maybe, in that I honestly have no idea how you'd have to wire things up.

Comment: @millimoose We've created a simple webservice in .net using Stream, and the WSDL generated is very different from what CXF (Java) generates when using DataHandler. So I think you are right, with WCF, using streaming requires some proprietary declarations.