# Sending large files from C# client to Glassfish using MTOM and streaming

Tags: java, c#, glassfish, streaming, mtom

I'm working on a web service that must be able to receive potentially large files (up to 2~3GB).

For the moment I configured a very simple test web service that runs in Glassfish :

```
package ch.geste.MTOMTest;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOM;

@MTOM
@WebService(name="ServiceMTOM_Svc")
public class ServiceMTOM {
    public int upload(@WebParam(name="filename") String filename, @WebParam(name="data") DataHandler data)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

On the client side (C#) I imported this web service, and the generated proxy method signature to call my upload function is :

```
public int upload(string filename, byte[] data)
```

My problem is that I want to stream the data variable, because it can be quite large. That's why on the server side I'm using the DataHandler class instead of a byte array.
But on client side, if I make a naive call to upload method like this (with a 3.8GB file) :

```
svc.upload(Path.GetFileName(path), File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

I get an exception because the C# program tries to load the whole file into memory... I understand that, I would crash too :)

So I think I need to pass a Stream object to the proxy method but I don't know how.

Do you have any idea?

Oh by the way, in my app.config, I set the transferMode="Streamed" in my binding tag.

Many thanks,

Nicolas

EDIT : Crap, I made a duplicate of an unanswered question... really sorry.
See [How to use Stream instead of byte[] in C# client with a Java MTOM webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421851/how-to-use-stream-instead-of-byte-in-c-sharp-client-with-a-java-mtom-webservic?rq=1)